# Find a 4 x 4 matrix with rational entries such that its fourth power is the identity matrix multiplied by -1

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

I am working on the following problem:

Find a $4 \times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $A^4 = -I$.

I know that if $A^4 = -I$, it would suffice to find a $4 \times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that its characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = x^4 + 1$, since every matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. In this case, it seems plausible to me that it would have to have main diagonal entries all $0$ in order to get the $x^4$ term showing up in $p(x)$. But when I try to vary what the off-diagonal entries are, then, I can't seem to get the appropriate characteristic polynomial. Is there a more clever way to approach this than to ad-hoc construct such a matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: There aren't necessarily zeros on the diagonal to get that characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Have you heard of the companion matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)? It allows you to construct a matrix with a desired minimal/characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Aah, I see. The problem is pretty easy now. Thanks! I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment, you can take the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$. You may check that this has the desired characteristic and minimal polynomial or just note that with $\{e_i\}$ the standard basis that this maps $e_1\to e_2\to e_3\to e_4\to -e_4$ so that it will have the desired property.